# What is the best way to create a parent/master entry in a DJANGO CRUD database app and then add associating data fields to the parent/master?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am in the process of creating a django to mysql CRUD database webapp and have run into some basic issues in understanding how to associate data fields.

This is what I have for my models.py and was wondering if this is even the correct way to setup the associations for a foreign key id? The idea is to have each hardareid_text contain multiple barcodeids.

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Hardwareid(models.Model):
    hardwareid_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.hardwareid_text

class Barcodeid1(models.Model):
    barcode1 = models.ForeignKey(Hardwareid)
    Barcodeid1_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #pub_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.Barcodeid1_text

class Barcodeid2(models.Model):
    barcode2 = models.ForeignKey(Hardwareid)
    Barcodeid2_text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.Barcodeid2_text
```

I have setup a view and wired it through a template so that a user can add a text description of the Hardwareid_text and I see it gets entered into mysql with an id, the hardwareid text and a datestamp.

```
class HardwareidForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
     model = Hardwareid
     fields = ['hardwareid_text']

def get_barcode(request):
   form = HardwareidForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = HardwareidForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        the_new_entry = form.save()
        return redirect('/successpage/')
   else:
     form = HardwareidForm()
   return render(request, 'get_barcode.html', {'form': form})
```

but I am not sure how to add barcodeid_texts and associate them with a single hardwareid_text. Would the best way be to look up the Hardwareid entry and then add the barcodeids at that point? If so how do I make sure they get attached/associated with the correct hardwareid_text database entry?

Thanks for any assistance or recommendations on this.

EDIT: I changed my forms.py to this and it still gives me an error:

```
class HardwareForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Hardware
        fields = ['text']

class BarcodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Barcode
        fields = ['text', 'hardware']
```

The error from the page access is:

```
ValidationError at /get_barcode.html
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_barcode.html
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value:    
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\formsets.py in management_form,     line 96
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['C:\\hwdb\\mysite',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
 Server time:   Mon, 24 Nov 2014 12:46:01 -0800
```

EDIT: added get_barcode.html page

```
<h1>Please enter the name of the Parent Hardware System<h1>

<form action='/get_barcode.html' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You don't need multiple barcode models. The fact that you have a ForeignKey from barcode to hardware *already* allows you to have multiple barcodes for each hardware: a ForeignKey defines a many-to-one relationship. Also, it doesn't make any sense to name the foreignkey after the model it is in: it needs to be named for the model it is pointing to, ie hardware. Finally, don't prefix your field names with the model name: that's unnecessary.

```
class Hardware(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.text

class Barcode(models.Model):
    hardware = models.ForeignKey(Hardware)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #pub_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    def __unicode__(self):             
        return self.text
```

Now, in order to enter the barcodes along with the hardware, you need to use an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

def get_barcode(request):
    BarcodeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Hardware, Barcode, form=BarcodeForm)
    hardware = Hardware()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HardwareForm(request.POST, instance=hardware)
        formset = BarcodeFormSet(request.POST, instance=hardeware)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            hardware = form.save()
            barcodes = formset.save()
            return redirect('/successpage/')
    else:
        form = HardwareForm(instance=hardware)
        formset = BarcodeFormSet(instance=hardeware)
   return render(request, 'get_barcode.html', {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Daniel. This seems like a much easier way to handle it. When I made the changes however I get an error that my forms.py needs to be updated. I saw that my barcode class did not have hardware asa field so i added it in but still received an error. Is there somewhere else where I need to set or define the hardware key?

Comment: From the command line I see the following error:

Calling modelformset_factory without defining 'fields' or 'exclude' explicitly is deprecated
  FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)

Calling modelform_factory without defining 'fields' or 'exclude' explicitly is deprecated
  labels=labels, help_texts=help_texts, error_messages=error_messages)

Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is deprecated - form BarcodeForm needs updating return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)

Comment: Ah, you need to pass your BarcodeForm into the inlineformset_factory, I've updated it above. You should also remove 'hardware' from the list of fields for that form, since you're defining it implicitly via the relationship.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help Daniel. I made the change and removed hardware from the field and am still getting the same exception. Do i need to update the HTML template for the page as well?

Comment: I don't know because you haven't shown the template, but you'll need to output at least `{{ form }}` and `{{ formset }}` (and I missed the formset from the context, added it now).

Comment: That might be the issue as I do not see those. I added the formset to the view but still have the same error.Someone else had helped me out on that page and I do not think I understand how that page/template is affected by the output of the view. I have added the page above. Thanks again Daniel.

Comment: Look at the documentation for formsets - in the template you need to output `formset.management_form` then iterate through `formset.forms`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel I will go through the docs to try and figure this out.